# Dell 3110cn USB printer not detected

Tags: usb, printing, cups

I have a Dell 3110cn printer that I was previously using as a **network** printer with success on my ArchLinux box.

Now I have to use it as a **USB** printer (I can't use LAN anymore) but it is not recognized as a printer by CUPS.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:644d Microdia 1.3 MPixel Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 413c:5605 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

as you may see, the device is listed

```
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 413c:5605 Dell Computer Corp.
```

however when I search for the new printer (`http://localhost:631/admin/`) is says "no printers found".

Please notice that it works as usb printer with Win and OSX.

Any idea?

**Edit**
Please note that after connecting the printer:

```
$ journalctl -e | grep printer
nov 24 16:12:47 dell-xps13-luca kernel: usblp 3-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 11 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x413C pid 0x5605
```

But it still does not show as a new printer...

Comment: If you are connecting by USB I don't think you would be able to connect to its web port (http://...), that doesn't mean you can't print to it via USB e.g. with CUPS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
First of all I implemented [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1037279#p1037279) workaround (below here is the updated version):

(as super user)

```
$ systemctl stop org.cups.cupsd.service
```

Then create `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-cups_device_link.rules` file and add this content:

```
KERNEL=="lp[0-9]", SYMLINK+="%k", GROUP="lp"
```

Unplug and plug the usb printer cable and wait a few seconds.
Finally restart cups

```
$ systemctl start org.cups.cupsd.service
```

The printer is now discovered by CUPS as a parallel port printer.
In my case unfortunately I could not install it via GUI tools as they were not able to find information about the drive to be used.
Fortunately CUPS comes with command line tool that I could use to install my printer

(as normal user, NO sudo)

```
$ lpadmin -p DELL_LaserJet_3110cn -E -v parallel:/dev/lp0 -P /usr/share/cups/model/Dell/Dell_3110cn.ppd
```

**Note:**

Path to the driver specified to the `-P` parameter you should find it by searching the PDD in your system

Device name (in my case `parallel:/dev/lp0`) to be specified to `-v` parameter, you can get by executing `lpinfo -v`